# metabox displaying on incorrect page

Tags: php, metabox

I've got two different functions that output different metabox's one is for the pages and the other is for just the post.

For some reason the one I created for posts overwrites the one on pages and displays on both the page and post admin panels.

I want each one to display on the relevant $page.

Page meta box code - http://pastebin.com/PdTzQ49f

post meta box code -http://pastebin.com/rh0ZJ1WU

If someone can tell me why the post meta box overwrites the page ones I would be very grateful as I've been searching for hours to find no solution.

Thanks

Comment: Seems to work correctly when I try it-- just the actual boxes, not the rest of the code.

Comment: Yeah the box appears but only the custom excerpt box appears and the otherone's are overwritten, do you get different meta box's on the pages and posts?

Comment: Is everything is "Screen Options" checked?

Comment: let me check s_ha_dum

Comment: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0631g76kc5 - this is what I see in the post

Comment: this is what i see in the page part http://awesomescreenshot.com/0891g76s75

Comment: The unchecked boxes are hidden.

Comment: Yes, There not my metabox thats ment to display on the pages, the one's here should be called Main page display and background colour

Comment: I am really sorry, but I don't understand the question.

Comment: I'm trying to get the correct meta box to display in the correct place one is assigned 'post' the other 'page'

Comment: I understand the basic idea, but it works correctly as far as I can tell when I use your _unaltered_ code.

Comment: you get the following meta box's for 'pages' background colour, display front page, and the following metabox for 'post' custom exerpt teaser

Comment: Saw your other post got deleted, but do paste the code in the question here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropping the code quickly into my test set up, I think you are asking why your page metabox is showing your desired post meta inputs.

There's no problem with your `add_meta_box()` functions.  The problem is with your variable `$custom_meta_fields`.  By the time WordPress gets to the end of your file `$custom_meta_fields` is defined by the array you are using for posts.  So your page metabox is using the post's version of `$custom_meta_fields`.  This is a side effect of using global variables the way you have.... they are easily overwritten.  The easiest thing to do would be use different variables:

```
// Add the Meta Box
function vs_add_custom_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'custom_meta_box', // $id
        'Custom Meta Box', // $title
        'vs_show_custom_meta_box', // $callback
        'page', // $page
        'normal', // $context
        'high'); // $priority
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'vs_add_custom_meta_box');

// Field Array
$prefix = 'custom_';
$custom_page_meta_fields = array(
    array(
        'label'=> 'Background Color',
        'desc'  => 'Select the color you want to appear as the page background.',
        'id'    => $prefix.'select',
        'type'  => 'select',
        'options' => array (
            'one' => array (
                'label' => 'Orange',
                'value' => 'blog'
            ),
            'two' => array (
                'label' => 'Light red',
                'value' => 'services'
            ),
            'three' => array (
                'label' => 'Dark red',
                'value' => 'works'
            ),
            'four' => array (
                'label' => 'Green',
                'value' => 'portfolio'
            ),
            'five' => array (
                'label' => 'Light blue',
                'value' => 'about'
            ),
            'six' => array (
                'label' => 'Dark blue',
                'value' => 'contact'
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'label'=> 'Main page display',
        'desc'  => 'Tick if this page will be displayed on the homepage. || Notice: Make sure there are no 2 pages with the same color displayed on the homepage.',
        'id'    => $prefix.'main',
        'type'  => 'checkbox'
    )
);

// The Callback
function vs_show_custom_meta_box() {  
global $custom_page_meta_fields, $post;
// Use nonce for verification
echo '<input type="hidden" name="custom_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';

    // Begin the field table and loop
    echo '<table class="form-table">';
    foreach ($custom_page_meta_fields as $field) {
        // get value of this field if it exists for this post
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
        // begin a table row with
        echo '<tr>
                <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th>
                <td>';
                switch($field['type']) {
                    // case items will go here
                    // text
case 'text':
    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$meta.'" size="30" />
        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
break;
// textarea
case 'textarea':
    echo '<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4">'.$meta.'</textarea>
        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
break;
// checkbox
case 'checkbox':
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" ',$meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '','/>
        <label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['desc'].'</label>';
break;
// select
case 'select':
    echo '<select name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'">';
    foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
        echo '<option', $meta == $option['value'] ? ' selected="selected"' : '', ' value="'.$option['value'].'">'.$option['label'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select><br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
break;
                } //end switch
        echo '</td></tr>';
    } // end foreach
    echo '</table>'; // end table
}

// Save the Data
function vs_save_custom_meta($post_id) {
    global $custom_page_meta_fields;

    // verify nonce
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))
        return $post_id;
    // check autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;
    // check permissions
    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))
            return $post_id;
        } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
    }

    // loop through fields and save the data
    foreach ($custom_page_meta_fields as $field) {
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];
        if ($new && $new != $old) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
        }
    } // end foreach
}
add_action('save_post', 'vs_save_custom_meta');



// Add the Meta Box
function vs_add_excerpt_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'excerpt_meta_box', // $id
        'Excerpt Meta Box', // $title
        'vs_show_excerpt_meta_box', // $callback
        'post', // $page
        'normal', // $context
        'high'); // $priority
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'vs_add_excerpt_meta_box');

// Field Array
$prefix = 'custom_';
$custom_post_meta_fields = array(
    array(
        'label' => 'Custom post teaser',
        'desc'  => 'Replace the default excerpt the text of your choice',
        'id'    => $prefix.'excerpt',
        'type'  => 'textarea'
        )
);

// The Callback
function vs_show_excerpt_meta_box() { 
global $custom_post_meta_fields, $post;
// Use nonce for verification
echo '<input type="hidden" name="excerpt_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';

    // Begin the field table and loop
    echo '<table class="form-table">';
    foreach ($custom_post_meta_fields as $field) {
        // get value of this field if it exists for this post
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
        // begin a table row with
        echo '<tr>
                <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th>
                <td>';
                switch($field['type']) {
                    // case items will go here
                    // text
case 'text':
    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$meta.'" size="30" />
        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
break;
// textarea
case 'textarea':
    echo '<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4">'.$meta.'</textarea>
        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
break;
// checkbox
case 'checkbox':
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" ',$meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '','/>
        <label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['desc'].'</label>';
break;
// select
case 'select':
    echo '<select name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'">';
    foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
        echo '<option', $meta == $option['value'] ? ' selected="selected"' : '', ' value="'.$option['value'].'">'.$option['label'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select><br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
break;
                } //end switch
        echo '</td></tr>';
    } // end foreach
    echo '</table>'; // end table
}

// Save the Data
function vs_save_excerpt_meta($post_id) {
    global $custom_post_meta_fields;

    // verify nonce
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['excerpt_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))
        return $post_id;
    // check autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;
    // check permissions
    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))
            return $post_id;
        } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
    }

    // loop through fields and save the data
    foreach ($custom_post_meta_fields as $field) {
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];
        if ($new && $new != $old) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
        }
    } // end foreach
}
add_action('save_post', 'vs_save_custom_meta');
```

You could also move your `$custom_meta_fields` inside a wrapper function, so that it can be called from any of the other functions.

```
// Add the Meta Box
function vs_add_excerpt_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'excerpt_meta_box', // $id
        'Excerpt Meta Box', // $title
        'vs_show_excerpt_meta_box', // $callback
        'post', // $page
        'normal', // $context
        'high'); // $priority
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'vs_add_excerpt_meta_box');

function vs_get_post_meta_fields(){
// Field Array
$prefix = 'custom_';
return array(
    array(
        'label' => 'Custom post teaser',
        'desc'  => 'Replace the default excerpt the text of your choice',
        'id'    => $prefix.'excerpt',
        'type'  => 'textarea'
        )
);
}

// The Callback
function vs_show_excerpt_meta_box() { 
global $post;
// Use nonce for verification
echo '<input type="hidden" name="excerpt_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';

    // get the array with proper scope
    $custom_post_meta_fields = vs_get_post_meta_fields();

    // Begin the field table and loop
    echo '<table class="form-table">';
    foreach ($custom_post_meta_fields as $field) {
        // get value of this field if it exists for this post
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
        // begin a table row with
        echo '<tr>
                <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th>
                <td>';
                switch($field['type']) {
                    // case items will go here
                    // text
case 'text':
    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$meta.'" size="30" />
        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
break;
// textarea
case 'textarea':
    echo '<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4">'.$meta.'</textarea>
        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
break;
// checkbox
case 'checkbox':
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" ',$meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '','/>
        <label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['desc'].'</label>';
break;
// select
case 'select':
    echo '<select name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'">';
    foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
        echo '<option', $meta == $option['value'] ? ' selected="selected"' : '', ' value="'.$option['value'].'">'.$option['label'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select><br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
break;
                } //end switch
        echo '</td></tr>';
    } // end foreach
    echo '</table>'; // end table
}

// Save the Data
function vs_save_excerpt_meta($post_id) {

    $custom_post_meta_fields = vs_get_post_meta_fields();


    // verify nonce
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['excerpt_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))
        return $post_id;
    // check autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;
    // check permissions
    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))
            return $post_id;
        } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
    }

    // loop through fields and save the data
    foreach ($custom_post_meta_fields as $field) {
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];
        if ($new && $new != $old) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
        }
    } // end foreach
}
add_action('save_post', 'vs_save_custom_meta');
```